# On existence of a tangent line passing through a given point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

## Question

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, and $C\subseteq\mathbb P^2(k)$ is an irreducible projective plane curve of degree $n>1$, and $P$ is a point on $\mathbb P^2(k)\setminus C$. Then there's $Q\in C$, such that the tangent cone of $C$ at $Q$ passes through $P$, i.e., there's a tangent line of $C$ passing through $P$.

## Background

I'm reading Motzkin & Taussky's paper *pairs of matrices with property L*. It seems that some stronger version of the preceding statement is involved in the proof of Theorem 3. I need to know how to show it.

Comment: One idea is to use duality. The dual of $C$ in the dual $\mathbf P^2$ is the set of all tangents to $C$; under your hypotheses, it is a curve. The set of all lines through $P$ is a line in the dual space. So these two intersect. I suppose the delicate point is to show that they intersect in a point that actually corresponds to a tangent of $C$. (If $C$ is smooth, there's no problem.)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh How to deal with singularities? The dual curve is usually defined as the image of $(\partial f/\partial x:\partial f/\partial y:\partial f/\partial z)$, which isn't well-defined at, say, double points.

Comment: But maybe all tangent lines corresponds to the Zariski closure of the corresponding points to tangent lines at nonsingular points. I guess that the closure is irreducible and then Bezout's theorem works. I don't know whether it is true.

Comment: Dear Frank Science, yes, that's the crux of the matter. One usually defines the dual curve as the closure of the image of the smooth locus. The key is then to show that the points you add in when taking the closure are actually lines in the tangent cone of singular points. I don't know the details offhand, I'm afraid.

Comment: Another idea would be the following: view the lines through $P$ as a $\mathbb{P}^1$, then mapping a point $Q$ to the line through $P$ and $Q$ gives a map from $C$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree greater than one. By Hurwitz's theorem, this map has to be ramified, but a ramification point corresponds to a tangent line of $C$.

Comment: @karl_christ: that's a very nice solution. But again I worry a bit about the technicalities: if the map is ramified at a singular point $Q$ of $C$, can we really conclude that $\overline{PQ}$ belongs to the tangent cone to $C$ at $Q$?

Comment: @Asal Beag Dubh: yes, you're right, i didn't think of that.